# Mostrar resultado en 2 cajas de texto con ajax

Tags: ajax

Deseo obterner dos resultados a traves de una consulta por ajax, por ahora solo obtengo una y lo muestro en una caja de texto:

***index.php:***

```
<script>
function enviar(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
data: datos,
//data: {nombre:n},
success: function(d){
  $("#respa").val(d);// ID de la 1era caja de texto
  $("#respa2").val(d);// ID de la 2da caja de texto
}

});
return false;
}
</script>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" name="" id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
  <input type="text" id="respa"><br>
  <input type="text" id="respa2"><br>// Aca deseo la 2da consulta
</form>
```

***prueba_consulta.php:***

```
<?php
//************ conexion a BD ***************
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("mantenimiento",$con);

 $filtro=$_POST["nombre"];
 $rs= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registro_energia_temp WHERE nombre_site like '%$filtro%' order by id_energia desc ;"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

echo $row['nombre_site']; //1er resultado q ingresa a la 1era caja de texto
echo $row['fecha_manto_energia'];// deseo mostrar en la segunda caja de texto
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener más valores debes enviarlos y recibirlos como un objeto `json` de la siguiente manera:

**index.php:**

```
<script>
function enviar(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
data: datos,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(d){
  $("#respa").val(d[0]);// ID de la 1era caja de texto
  $("#respa2").val(d[1]);// ID de la 2da caja de texto
}

});
return false;
}
</script>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" name="" id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
  <input type="text" id="respa"><br>
  <input type="text" id="respa2"><br>// Aca deseo la 2da consulta
</form>
```

**prueba_consulta.php:**

```
<?php
//************ conexion a BD ***************
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("mantenimiento",$con);

 $filtro=$_POST["nombre"];
 $rs= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registro_energia_temp WHERE nombre_site like '%$filtro%' order by id_energia desc ;"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

$datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre_site'], $row['fecha_manto_energia']);

echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
```

Comment: Simplemente, excelente!!!

Comment: Si te funcionó te invito a que aceptes la respuesta para que los demás desarrolladores que algún día tengan un problema similar sepan cual fue la solución correcta, además te invito a que te hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y por supuesto bienvenido a Stackoverflow !